# Nested array in json data in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli, nested

I need to show Mysql data in json nested array like

```
{
    "status": true,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Title 1",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Title 2",
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "Title 3",
        }
    ]
}
```

Code I am trying is

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
$res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
    $rows[] = $row;
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $rows = ['id' => $row['id'], 'title' => $row['title']];             
    }
}

    
    $data = array('status' => true, 'categories' => array($rows));
    echo json_encode($data);
```

But what I get is only with one record in the nested array i.e

```
{
    "status": true,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Title 1",
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve my requirement?

Comment: $rows[] = ['id' => $row['id'], 'title' => $row['title']];

Comment: @splash58 now it is showing all but with duplications.

Comment: Why is there a foreach loop nested into the while loop to begin with here? That makes no sense.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I used because I was not able to get all records in the array so I thought to use foreach so it would loop in for all records.

Comment: That is not only totally unnecessary, but you did it so wrong, that you are completely destroying your data there. You loop over `$rows`, and then _overwrite_ `$rows` - not a single entry _in_ that array, but the _complete_ array, with something completely different inside the loop body.

Comment: Start by making the query return only the columns you are interested in: `SELECT id, title FROM …`. Then, go read up on the parameters for `mysqli_fetch_array` - you want that to fetch a row as an associative array. And then, inside the while loop, you simply add that associative array as a new element into your rows array, just `$rows[] = $row;`

Comment: // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
//$res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$result = $conn->query($sql);


$rows = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

$data = json_encode($rows);
$conn->close();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid duplication, leave out the `foreach` loop and just write in the while loop:

```php
$rows[] = ['id' => $ row ['id'], 'title' => $ row ['title']];
```

…because with the `while` loop, you already run through the row array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any loops. Mysqli already returns a nested array which you can directly output to JSON

```
$res_data = $conn->query("SELECT id, title FROM `categories`")

echo json_encode(['status' => true, 'categories' => $res_data->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)]);
```